# issue in taking backup of messages in MQ using dmpmqmsg

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

We faced a issue in production.A queue has curdepth of 176.but while taking backup,its showing only 170 messages . There is no uncommitted messages also.. why 6 messages are not getting backed up?
[image]

Issued command:-

```
dmpmqmsg -m <qmname> -i <queuename> -f <filename>
```

[image]

When I checked using the `amqsbcg` sample program, I could see all 176 messages. 176 headers were there. There were no empty messages.

Comment: Can you add the parameters you are using for dmpmqmsg?

Comment: dmpmqmsg -m <qmname>  -i <queuename> -f <filename>

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts:

(1) From the time you issued the 'dis ql({qname})' command to you running the dmpmqmsg program, 6 messages could have been consumed by another program.

(2) Those 6 messages could be expired messages.

(3) Even though UNCOM has a value of 'NO', you can run the dspmqtrn program to see if there are any uncommitted messages:

Internally coordinated:

```
dspmqtrn -i -m {QMgrName}
```

Externally coordinated:

```
dspmqtrn -e -m {QMgrName}
```

Comment: 1. After taking backup also,curdepth remains to be same.(i.e 176). hence,its not consumed by another application. 3./opt/mqm/bin/dspmqtrn -m <qmname>
"There are no matching prepared or heuristically completed transactions" --> output i received. 2.how to check whether messages are expired?

Comment: Can it be maybe segmented messages? I can’t find whether dmpmqmsg gets with reassembly enabled, but that could also explain this.

Comment: dmpmqmsg does not asks for MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG, so each segment will be dumped as an individual message. However, even if it was, you should be able to see this in the output file. Look at the last three fields of the MQMD of each message. You have OFF (Offset), MSF (MsgFlags) and ORL (OriginalLength) which will be set to various values when the messages are segments. If the message is not a segment, you will see OFF = 0, MSF = 0 and ORL = -1.

Comment: If, after running the dmpmqmsg command, your curdepth is still the same, that does suggest it isn't expired messages, because they would now be removed from the queue, and thus no longer count towards the curdepth. If you use a message browsing tool, can you see 176 messages or only 170?

Comment: curdepth is still 176

Comment: Yes indeed @Sowmiya- as you said. So what can you see with a message browsing tool? Perhaps update your question with a screenshot?

Comment: Had another though @Sowmiya. I haven't tested this theory out, but is it possible that this queue has an AMS security policy and you're not being returned the messages that your user doesn't have access to see? Use DISPLAY POLICY(q-name) to see whether it does.

Comment: Update on my previous comment @Sowmiya - I finally got around to testing this and it can't be the case as you would get a bad return code (2063) if you were unable to read messages due to AMS encryption policies being in place, so dmpmqmsg wouldn't be quiet about it.

Comment: Another possibility I thought of I have also now discarded. I wondered if it might be a zero length message, but no, dmpmqmsg still writes out the MQMD for it even if there is no content, so it's not that. Any news on the view with a message browsing tool @Sowmiya

Comment: when i checked using amqsbcg,i could see 176 messages..176 headers were there. and its not a empty messages..

Comment: Hi @Sowmiya - so what was different about the 6 messages that amqsbcg could see that dmpmqmsg could not see? Were you running the amqsbcg program using the same credentials as the dmpmqmsg program? Update your original question with the details.